# Как вернуть результат из callback в функцию

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой асинхронного выполнения запросов. Подскажите, как правильно написать код:

```html
// Determine the only image extension on the url
function getImgType(objUrl) {
 var res = null;
 chrome.downloads.search({url: objUrl}, function(items) {
  var mime = items[0].mime;
  if (mime.indexOf('image/') == 0) {
   res = mime.substring(6);
   console.log('1- res = ' + res);
  };
 });
 console.log('2- res = ' + res);
 return res;
};
```

Результат работы:

> 2- res = null
>   1- res = jpeg

Нужно чтобы `getImgType` вернула результат только после завершения работы `callback` в функции `function(items)`.

Comment: [отличное объяснение вариантов решения](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) правда на английском

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Результат работы правильный, у вас скрипт выполняется в однопоточной среде, поэтому вы сначала увидели результат переменной `res` равной null, затем сработал асинхронный callback переданный в функцию `search` и переменной `res` присвоилось заначение `jpeg`. Правильно будет передавать callback в функцию `getImgType` или использовать [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
function getImgType(objUrl, callback) {
    chrome.downloads.search({url: objUrl}, function(items) {
        var mime = items[0].mime;
        if (mime.indexOf('image/') == 0) {
            callback(mime.substring(6));
        };
    });
};
```

И собственно вызов

```
getImgType("http://some-url/", function(mimeType){
   // какие-то операции с mimeType
});
```

C использованием Promise

```
function getImgType(objUrl){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         chrome.downloads.search({url: objUrl}, function(items) {
             var mime = items[0].mime;
             if (mime.indexOf('image/') == 0) {
                 resolve(mime.substring(6));
             } else {
                 reject(new Error("Incorrect mime type")
             }
         });
    });
}
```

Вызов функции getImgType будет выглядеть теперь иначе

```
getImgType("http://some-url/")
      .then(function(mimeType){
          // какие-то операции с mimeType
      })
      .catch(function(err){
          // обработка ошибки 
      });
```

Comment: а return promise не нужен?

Comment: Премного благодарен !!! Выбрал первый вариант, все работает.

Comment: @рони, нужен, иначе будет исключение что у undefined нет метода then

Comment: ошибся в примере, нужен конечно

Comment: @hijeane Если при выполнении скрипта необходимо несколько раз вызывать getImgType(objUrl, callback), то не могу вызывать function(mimeType) для основного кода скрипта. Возможно ли изменить getImgType так, чтобы получить такой вызов mimeType = getImgType("http://some-url/"); ?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить вызов типа mimeType = getImgType("http://some-url/") необходимо использовать синхронный запрос, чего делать крайне не рекомендуется. Однако, если по-другому решить поставленную задачу не удается, то для коротеньких запросов заголовка страниц можно использовать следующий код:

```
function getImgType(objUrl) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('HEAD', objUrl, false);
  try {
    xhr.send();
  } catch(err) {
      return;
    };
  var imgType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
  if (imgType) {
    if (imgType.indexOf('image/') == 0) {
      return imgType.substring(6);
    };
  };
};
```

И собственно вызов:

```
mimeType = getImgType("http://some-url/");
```

Comment: Синхронный запрос -- это не решение проблемы. Совсем. Это всего лишь костыль. Правильные варианты решения проблемы уже были озвучены в соседнем ответе.