# Можно сделать такую функцию в JS без обратного вызова :(

Tags: javascript, ajax

Я прочитал пост: [Как вернуть результат из callback в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490535/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-callback-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)
но там так и не нашёл ответа, как вызвать некоторую функцию, в которой идёт запрос к серверу, которая бы ждала ответ от сервера и уже потом именно сама возвращала его. Не в callback функции что-то делать!
Есть вот такая функция:

```js
function requestServer(pathScript, stringParameters)
{
  var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
  
  xmlhttp.open('POST', path_main_dir + pathScript, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send(stringParameters);
  
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
      {
        return xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
  }
}
```

и уже где-то в коде чтобы можно было пользоваться ей вот так:

```js
var text = requestServer('php/connect.php', 'request=get_time');
```

Но я начинаю подозревать что такое наверное не возможно сделать  :(

Просто согласитесь что так гораздо бы читабильнее получался код чем если сделать с функцией обратного вызова, то есть вот так:

```js
  requestServer('/php/connection.php', 'request=get_time', function(response){
    // и уже вот здесь что-то делаю с ответом response
  });
```

Не нравится мне такое использование :(

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Нельзя. Нельзя. Сколько ещё раз это нужно повторить?

Comment: Блин.. Ну всё же русским языком написано...

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял суть вашего вопроса, то могу немного пояснить. Функция обратного вызова - это потребность (!) языка вследствие его уникальной архитектуры. Вы должны знать, что JS является асинхронным, т.е. выполнение всех I/O-функций, связанных с вводом/выводом данных, то есть чтение и запись в файл, посыл HTTP-запросов и т.д., будет происходить не в основном потоке. Но чтобы как-то обработать результат тех функций, были придуманы коллбэки. После того, как завершится посыл запроса в коллбэк в качестве параметра будет занесен ответ, а далее с ним будут те действия, которые вы описали. 
В плане удобства, как вы отметили, это некрасиво. В плане работы программы - это гениально. Объясню почему. Если вы будете делать запрос и ждать ответа в главном потоке, то это остановит его, тем самым ваша страница или сервер будут неспособны обрабатывать какие-либо иные действия, т.е. например вы не сможете кликать на какие-то кнопки или ещё что-то. Ваша страница будет просто непригодной к использованию.
Однако с развитием языка JS, в стандарте появилась очень интересная конструкция `async/await`. Эта конструкция является синтаксическим сахаром над `Promise` (если интересно, что это, то погуглить), но в целом данная конструкция позволит вам сделать то, что вы хотите.
В целом, сейчас для запросов на проектах используется `axios`. Тогда вы сможете писать код примерно так:

```
async function sendRequest(url) {
  const data = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(data);
}
```

Данный код представляет из себя примерно то, что вы хотите. Только он не блокирует основной поток и ваше приложение будет способным к обработке других событий.

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО что не поленились написать, Promise я возьму на вооружение :)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто ответил! Решил сделать так:

```js
function requestServer(pathScript, stringParameters, callback)
{
  var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
  
  xmlhttp.open('POST', path_main_dir + pathScript, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send(stringParameters);
  
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
      {
        callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
  }
}
```

Использую функцию теперь вот так:

```js
requestServer('/php/connect.php', 'request=get_time', function(response){
    document.getElementById('id_element').innerHTML = response;
    // какие либо ещё действия над response или другие 
    // действия, которые должны выполниться после ответа сервера
  });
```

Не стал усложнять всё промисами, как по мне, код становится только сложнее, особой красоты оформленияи восприятия кода (что для меня ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО) при использовании промисов не увидел, да и не думаю что оно быстрее выполняться будет, ведь в чем большее количество оболочек код заворачивать, тем потом оно дольше и выполняется :(